# Using The ORM in controller SilverStripe

Tags: orm, silverstripe

I have the following layout:

**mypage.ss**

```
$CreateString
<% loop $LatestString %>
    <div>$StringVar</div>
<% end_loop>
```

**mypage.php**

```
class MyPage extends Page {

    private static $db = array(
        'StringVar' => 'Varchar'
    );
}

class MyPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    public function CreateString() { 
        $varS = MyPage::create(array('StringVar' => 'Jonh Davies')); 
        $varS = MyPage::write(); 
        return $varS;
    }

    public function LatestString() { 
        return MyPage::get()
            ->sort('Created', 'DESC')
            ->limit(1);
    } 
}
```

The thing is nothing is created and there is now output from the controller. No record created, and no output.

Comment: Are you testing it on on a MyPage_Controller? Did you flush? You can call the controller directly by calling the name of the controller in the url, e.g. `http://example.com/MyPage_Controller/`

Comment: I'm calling $CreateString and $LatestString in my mypage.ss layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above example MyPage is not published. Your CreateString method should look more like:

```
$varS = MyPage::create(...);
$varS->write();
$varS->publish('Stage', 'Live');
return $varS;
```

I'm not even sure what "MyPage::write" will do but it probably is not even saving the record in the staging table to begin with. I'm a little surprised that's not generating an error.

Comment: mypage.ss is in the Layouts folder, why is it mypage.ss not published?

Comment: you have to publish a page manually, cause it has Versioned extension plugged in, and write() just writes to stage databasetable.
Can you see a page created in database?

Comment: How do I know if a page has a Versioned extension plugged in?

Comment: All Page objects do. It's added in the code for SiteTree in a line that looks like: "private static $extensions = array("Versioned(Stage,Live)","Hierarchy")" or something similar. The easiest way to tell is to look at the database and see if there is one single table or three tables (the classname, and one suffixed _Live and one _versions).

Comment: @MarkGuinn,@wmk, or anybody, please help me understand the example from http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/introduction-to-the-orm?ref=hub, I think I understand the  $LatestArticles function part. But where do I define the creation of the records like in the first part of the lesson where $product = Product::create(); Creation goes to controller or where? I'm trying to populate tables coming from a large dataset (from textfile) into defined tables in SIlverstripe.

Comment: Do imports in a BuildTask which you can run manually or as a cron job. See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/cli/ for more info. Your controller should only be consuming data that's already in the database.

Comment: @Mark, which one do you recommend BuildTask or DataObject->requireDefaultRecords()?

Comment: Use requireDefaultRecords if you have a small, fixed number of records to create. Use a BuildTask if you're importing data. If you use requireDefaultRecords, check that the table is empty before you do anything because it will get called every time dev/build is run.